# How to smoothly change colors when hold on button on android?

Tags: android, button

In my app, I have a button, that uses a style, and the style references a selector background, which then defined a shape xml for its default and pressed states.

If I click the button, it instantly changes to the pressed state.

How can I make it so it, smoothly changes color as you hold it, and it takes 1 second to fully transition, like a transition effect? (if you let go, it should transition back to original state)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_button_default" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_button_default" />
</selector>
```

circle_button_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff9517"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

circle_button_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#d47300"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to set animation for the button

```
Animation fadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
```

press Ctrl+Shift+'O' to add necessary packages then apply the animation to the buttons as follows:

```
public void click (View v){
 button1.startAnimation(fadeout);}
```

If you are planning to animate many buttons stick them to a grid and apply the animation to it.

Comment: This will cause the animation to run when you click the button and then if you let go, it will still continue the animation until it finishes. I want it so that the animation will run only while you are holding the button. If you let go, it should reverse the animation and transition back to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `OnTouchListener` on your button and then from there you can check if button current pressed or already pressed

**example:**

```
    youBUtton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // on release
        }else{
           // on touch
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I detect when they let go of button?

Comment: @omega if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

Comment: then how do u detect when u touch the button?

Comment: @omega on the else block

Comment: @omega ya my bad on that one